# Find dimensions of Kalman decomposition subspaces from range of controllability & nullspace of observability matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a 4 by 4 matrix A in a linear system of $$\dot{x}=Ax+Bu$$ $$y=Cx$$. I am trying to determine just the dimension of each of the 4 different (un)controllable and (un)observable subspace submatrices of A after Kalman decomposition from just the range of controllability matrix and the nullspace of the observability matrice for this system. But I am not sure how to find the exact size of those submatrices.

For example if the range of the controllability matrix is spanned by $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}^T$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}^T$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}^T$ and the nullspace of the observability matrix is spanned by $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}^T$, we know the controllable and unobservable subspace $A_{c\bar{o}}$ is 1 by 1 because there is one basis vector that is both controllable and unobservable and $A_{\bar{c}\bar{o}}$ doesn't exist because everything that is unobservable is controllable. But because A is 4 by 4, that means either $A_{co}$ or $A_{\bar{c}o}$ is 2 by 2 and the other is 1 by 1. How can I determine the dimensions of those two subspaces?

And what happens when the range of the controllability matrix and nullpsace of observability are spanned by the same set of basis vectors?